# How to disable and destroy multiple buttons in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

There are 2 issues I'm facing at the moment.

1. When I click "Mike" button and and all Mike's sub buttons, I want the previous row buttons to be disabled but not button "Sara"
2. When I click "Sara" button I want Mike's sub buttons to be destroyed and returned to original state.

Having a hard time wrapping my head around the functionality. I feel like I'm taking a long route. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tk
app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("300x300")

def buttonA1State():
        if (buttonA1['state'] == tk.NORMAL):
            buttonA1['state'] = tk.DISABLED
        else:
            buttonA1['state'] = tk.NORMAL

def btn3():
    buttonA2 = tk.Button(app, text="Button A2",command = lambda:[buttonA1State(), btn5()])
    buttonA2.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=2, column=1)
    buttonA3 = tk.Button(app, text="Button A3",command=btn4)
    buttonA3.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=2, column=2)

def btn4():
    buttonA4 = tk.Button(app, text="Button A4")
    buttonA4.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=3, column=2)

def btn5():
    buttonA5 = tk.Button(app, text="Button A5")
    buttonA5.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=3, column=1)   

buttonA1 = tk.Button(app, text="Mike", command = lambda:[buttonA1State(), btn3()])
buttonA1.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=1, column=1)
buttonB1 = tk.Button(app, text="Sara", command = btn3 )
buttonB1.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=1, column=2)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can group multiple widget in separate `tk.Frame` widgets. Doing so would allow you to toggle the visibility of them all as well as destroy them by manipulating their containing `Frame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You say you want to disable to the previous row, but you have no way to identify which buttons are in a row. You need to find a logical way to process your buttons preferably avoiding hard coding every button as you are when the actions have similarities. Creating an array of buttons might work where the list number is associated with grid position.

```py
names = [["Mike", "Sara"]]
buttons = []
for x in range(names):
    buttons.append()
    for y in range(names[x]):
        buttons[x].append(Button(app, text=names[x][y])))
```

The above code would allow you to refer to your buttons using easy to understand matrices you would have to adjust slightly since you start your buttons on row 1 but that is easily done. You would need a global value to keep up with which row and column is active.

2. You should create all possible buttons first then you use the grid() and grid_forget() methods to change which buttons are showing. You may need to organize your buttons in list (related to Mike or Sara) to help process them. If you want your program to scale easily and the buttons for Mike and Sara are similar buttons then you may want to create a class.

```py
class APerson:
    def __init__(self, window, name):
        self.name = name
        self.selected = False
        self.select_button = Button(window, text=self.name command=select)
        self.secondary_button = Button(window, text="Secondary")
        self.another_button = Button(window, text="More Buttons")

    def toggle_select(self):
        self.selected = not self.selected


mike = APerson(app, "Mike")
sara = APerson(app, "Sara")


def main_callback:
    if mike.selected:
    etc...

app.after(1000, main_callback)
```

These are abstracts that you may find helpful. There are a lot of ways to do things in python and in programming in general so you really have to go with what makes the most sense for the problem you are trying to solve. You may prefer to create row objects that you pass buttons to instead of people objects that have buttons. I would avoid hard coding every action especially if you need your program to scale at all though.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the explanation as well :)